# Cannot configure nginx reverse proxy with php support in docker compose

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have been attempting to configure nginx reverse proxy with php support in docker compose that runs an app service on port 3838. I want the app to run the nginx-proxy on port 80. I have combed through several tutorials online but none of them has helped me resolve the problem. I also tried to follow this https://github.com/dmitrym0/simple-lets-encrypt-docker-compose-sample/blob/master/docker-compose.yml but it didn't work. Here is my current docker compose file.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
 nginx-proxy:
   image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
   ports:
     - "82:80"
     - "444:443"
   volumes:
     - "/etc/nginx/vhost.d"
     - "/usr/share/nginx/html"
     - "/var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro"
     - "/etc/nginx/certs"

app:
 build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: ./app/Dockerfile
 image: rocker/shiny
 container_name: docker-app
 restart: always
 ports:
  - 3838:3838
```

Am I missing something. Sometimes I see virtual_host environment variables include in the docker-compose file. Is that needed? Also do I have to manually configure nginx config files and attach them to the jwilder/nginx-proxy dockerfile? I a newbie at docker and and I really need some help.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the **Multiple Ports** section of the [nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) official docs. In your case, besides setting a mandatory `VIRTUAL_HOST` env variable (without this a container won't be reverse proxied by the `nginx-proxy` service), you have to set the `VIRTUAL_PORT` variable as the `nginx-proxy` will default to the service running on port `80`, but your `app` service is bind to `3838` port.

Try this `docker-compose.yml` file to see if it works:

```
version: "3"

services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro

  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./app/Dockerfile
    image: rocker/shiny
    container_name: docker-app
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 3838
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=app.localhost
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=3838
```